# Auto Approval in Approval Process

Tags: approval-process, field-update

I have an approval process with initial criteria Amount<3000.
In this process, I have a user X who should auto-approve the approvals.
So In the approval steps, I added criteria opposite to the initial criteria, so that this criteria would be skipped and it goes to the else and approves the record.
[image]

But here the approval is done by the current user itself(so the submitter and the approver are the same).

If I give "All records should enter this step" then it goes to the next step and to the automated approver chosen there the approval is submitted and he/she has to manually approve it.

My challenge is the approval should be done automatically but it should be done by a user I choose.

Is there any way to achieve this through automation? I understand that it isn't possible through the standard approval process.

Or should I customize the process?